# Dart json_serializable erro, Dart analysis: expected this library to be part of "....User.dart",not "......user.dart"

Tags: flutter, dart

I was using **build_runner** and **json_serializable** to bind my json model,but get a error

This is my code structure:

[image: lib/models]

My user.dart was:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'user.g.dart';


@JsonSerializable()
class User extends Object {

  @JsonKey(name: 'login')
  String login;

  @JsonKey(name: 'avatar_url')
  String avatarUrl;

  @JsonKey(name: 'type')
  String type;

  @JsonKey(name: 'name')
  String name;

  @JsonKey(name: 'company')
  String company;

  @JsonKey(name: 'blog')
  String blog;

  @JsonKey(name: 'location')
  String location;

  @JsonKey(name: 'email')
  String email;

  @JsonKey(name: 'hireable')
  bool hireable;

  @JsonKey(name: 'bio')
  String bio;

  @JsonKey(name: 'public_repos')
  int publicRepos;

  @JsonKey(name: 'followers')
  int followers;

  @JsonKey(name: 'following')
  int following;

  @JsonKey(name: 'created_at')
  String createdAt;

  @JsonKey(name: 'updated_at')
  String updatedAt;

  @JsonKey(name: 'total_private_repos')
  int totalPrivateRepos;

  @JsonKey(name: 'owned_private_repos')
  int ownedPrivateRepos;

  User(this.login,this.avatarUrl,this.type,this.name,this.company,this.blog,this.location,this.email,this.hireable,this.bio,this.publicRepos,this.followers,this.following,this.createdAt,this.updatedAt,this.totalPrivateRepos,this.ownedPrivateRepos,);

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> srcJson) => _$UserFromJson(srcJson);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);

}
```

After command run `flutter packages pub run build_runner watch`
,I get this **user.g.dart**:

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'user.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

User _$UserFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return User(
    json['login'] as String,
    json['avatar_url'] as String,
    json['type'] as String,
    json['name'] as String,
    json['company'] as String,
    json['blog'] as String,
    json['location'] as String,
    json['email'] as String,
    json['hireable'] as bool,
    json['bio'] as String,
    json['public_repos'] as int,
    json['followers'] as int,
    json['following'] as int,
    json['created_at'] as String,
    json['updated_at'] as String,
    json['total_private_repos'] as int,
    json['owned_private_repos'] as int,
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$UserToJson(User instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'login': instance.login,
      'avatar_url': instance.avatarUrl,
      'type': instance.type,
      'name': instance.name,
      'company': instance.company,
      'blog': instance.blog,
      'location': instance.location,
      'email': instance.email,
      'hireable': instance.hireable,
      'bio': instance.bio,
      'public_repos': instance.publicRepos,
      'followers': instance.followers,
      'following': instance.following,
      'created_at': instance.createdAt,
      'updated_at': instance.updatedAt,
      'total_private_repos': instance.totalPrivateRepos,
      'owned_private_repos': instance.ownedPrivateRepos,
    };
```

But the **dart analysis** show:

[image]

The error only happened on my **user.part**,other **.part**(like **profille.part,repo.part**)not.
I wanna know why this error occured

Comment: Same error occured to me , along on my user file! And it happened when I updated my flutter fire libraries. Did you do something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same thing happened to me. Here is how I fixed it:

I copied the code of user.dart into another text editor and completely deleted user.dart and user.g.dart

then I created a new user.dart and pasted the contents back. And then I ran flutter packages pub run build_runner watch and it fixed the issue.

I think what happened is that you (and I) accidentally created "User.dart" instead of "user.dart", and VSCode cached this somewhere and looked it up from the cache. But that is just my guess.

Comment: Unfortunately, the error came back :( So this ain't the answer. Were you able to fix it?

Comment: I had modified the user model's name ,So I can't verify this answer now.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution for this problem, that I've found is closing VSCode, then deleting cache directories from your's project repository(like .dart_tool, .vscode) and running the build_runner again.

Comment: After deleting remember to run `dart pub get` to get all your packages back if you need to

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to go to the generated .g.dart file, and then there correct the part of statement to refer to the correct file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename that file to another name and rename that file name back to the original name.

I am able to solve this issue via above method.

Answer (score 0):

Just closing and reopening vs code did the trick for me.